# R Shiny - Paths of logo and CSS file when I split ui and server files

Tags: css, r, path, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny dashboard that I have separated into three files : main (data and call to a generic dashboard), user interface (`ui.R` file) and server (`server` file).

I have a logo in the dashboard header and a CSS file, therefore I have a `www` directory in the directory of my code.

When I launch the app with the `ui` file it works but it doesn't when i launch the app with the main file (precision : the app works when I comment the CSS line of code but the logo is still not displayed).

A simplified example of my code is below.

Main

```
# Library and function
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

CountPlotFunction <- function(MyData)
{
  MyPlot <- ggplot(data = MyData, aes(x = MyData)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count", aes(fill = MyData)) +
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..)) +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  return(MyPlot)
}


# The data
var1 <- c("Russia","Canada","Australia","Australia","Russia","Australia","Canada","Germany","Australia","Canada","Canada")
var2 <- c("UnitedStates","France","SouthAfrica","SouthAfrica","UnitedStates","SouthAfrica","France","Norge","SouthAfrica","France","France")
var3 <- c("Brazil","Colombia","China","China","Brazil","China","Colombia","Belgium","China","Colombia","Colombia")
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)


# Call the app
source(paste0(TheFileDirectory,"server.R"))
source(paste0(TheFileDirectory,"ui.R"))
shinyApp(ui = Interface, server = Serveur)
```

User interface

```
# The Shiny app 
Interface <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",

  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard",
    dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu"),
      tags$li(class = "dropdown",
        tags$a(href = "http://google.com", tags$img(src = "Logo.png", height = "20px")))
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),

  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(includeCSS("www/style.css")),

      fluidPage(
        selectInput(inputId = "Question",
                    label = "Choose the question",
                    choices = colnames(df),
                    selected = colnames(df)[1]),
        mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "ThePlot"))
    )
  )  
)
```

Server

```
Serveur <- function(input, output)
{
  output$ThePlot <- renderPlot({CountPlotFunction(MyData = df[input$Question])})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the css include, call `setwd(TheFileDirectory)` before calling `source` or reference the full path to the css. But note this is not good practice and you will have a lot of renaming to apply whenever the path to the app changes.
(Instead you might want to run the app from its folder and reference the data. Thta wayy all your renaming would be at the same place)

To fix the logo, you can add a prefix to its source :

```
src = "/foo/logo.png"
```

Then make this call before starting the app with `shinyApp` :

```
addResourcePath("foo", "www")
```

It will make shiny start serving the folder `www` to the reference `/foo`

Comment: How I must add `addResourcePath` ? I try in the three files and I have the same error `Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : path[1]="www": No such file or directory`

Comment: Try using `setwd(TheFileDirectory)` first

Comment: this won't work on css. call `setwd(TheFileDirectory)` before sourcing ui.R and keep with "www/style.css"

Comment: if you start having this kind of problem, restart R